# How to add multiple textviews inside linear layout in .XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml

My `TextView` is not displaying in the Screen.

```
This app shows information from your SIM card and gets your MAC address. If you have 2 SIM cards inserted, information from SIM card in slot 1 will be retrieved.
Mobile Country Code
Mobile Network Code
Radio Type
Mac Address
Cell Id
Location Area code
```

The code I used in the mainactivity.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.onlyus.test1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/intro" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/mcc_code" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/mnc_code" />
```

However it just outputs the text from the first textview. I have defined `mcc_code` and `mnc_code` in **strings.xml** But it does not output the string. I just started coding apk file. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: change height of every textview to wrap_content.

Comment: according to your picture you attached..you did not change 1st textview height from **android:layout_height="match_parent"**  to **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your all `TextView`height `match_parent` to `wrap_content`
it will solve your Problem.

So Change this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/intro" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/mcc_code" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/mnc_code" />
```

to this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/intro" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mcc_code" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mnc_code" />
```

**For Put Space**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mcc_code" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mnc_code"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

**For Font Size :**

Add this property

```
android:textSize="16sp"
```

Comment: Nothing changed. The output still remained the same

Comment: What if I add another linear layout and add one textview in that linear layout?

Comment: I just put the picture in the post. I do not know how to post a picture in a comment.

Comment: @JezreelMartin `clean` the project and `rebuild`. may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: how do I do that? I am sorry because i am a total noob at this

Comment: @JezreelMartin in top menu `Build > Clean project` and `Build > Rebuild project`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123235/discussion-between-jezreel-martin-and-ironman).

Comment: @JezreelMartin if in future any problem occure free feel to ask.

Comment: ok. You will be the one I'll first consult upon proggressing with android apk programming